# How do you install OpenBLAS on Windows 10?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, openblas

I am trying to run PySpark on my machine but my program keeps ending unexpectedly and giving me the following warnings:

```
WARN netlib.BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
WARN netlib.BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
```

And I believe this might be the reason program isn't finishing. The [instructions in their github](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java#windows) are really vague. Can someone give me a step by step on how to install it?